# segmentation fault in glCreateBuffers

Tags: opengl

I am trying to run an example from the redbook 8th edition and I am receiving a segmentation fault in line:

`glCreateBuffers( NumBuffers, Buffers );`

file.cpp

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Triangles.cpp
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "vgl.h"
#include "LoadShaders.h"

enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOs };
enum Buffer_IDs { ArrayBuffer, NumBuffers };
enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0 };

GLuint  VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint  Buffers[NumBuffers];

const GLuint  NumVertices = 6;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// init
//

void
init( void )
{
    glGenVertexArrays( NumVAOs, VAOs );
    glBindVertexArray( VAOs[Triangles] );

    GLfloat  vertices[NumVertices][2] = {
        { -0.90f, -0.90f }, {  0.85f, -0.90f }, { -0.90f,  0.85f },  // Triangle 1
        {  0.90f, -0.85f }, {  0.90f,  0.90f }, { -0.85f,  0.90f }   // Triangle 2
    };

    glCreateBuffers( NumBuffers, Buffers );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer] );
    glBufferStorage( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, 0);

    ShaderInfo  shaders[] =
    {
        { GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert" },
        { GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triangles.frag" },
        { GL_NONE, NULL }
    };

    GLuint program = LoadShaders( shaders );
    glUseProgram( program );

    glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT,
                           GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// display
//

void
display( void )
{
    static const float black[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black);

    glBindVertexArray( VAOs[Triangles] );
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// main
//


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( !glfwInit() )
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "Triangles", NULL, NULL);
    if ( !window )
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewInit();

    init();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        display();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

I am compiling :

`g++ -O2 -g -o run opengl.cpp LoadShaders.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lglut -lglfw -lX11 -lm`

Comment: Does your `LoadShaders` check if the shader compilation and linking fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glCreateBuffers` is an OpenGL 4.5 function but you are using OpenGL 2.0 context, you need to use `glGenBuffers` instead.

Comment: Hmm..I didn't know it!Thanks! It works without seg fault.But it shows me a black window even though I am loading GL_VERTEX_SHADER, and FRAGMENT_SHADER.

Comment: glCreateBuffers is also intended to be used with the DSA API so if you're using it you definitely should not be using glBindBuffer or glBufferStorage.